# Prevent passing inherited object to shared function

Tags: vb.net, inheritance

I have a really contrived example to as how my business objects load their data. However I'd like to prevent the situation demonstrated below. I know there are shortcomings here, but it's just how it is (so far)! How can I achieve this without restructuring to interfaces etc?

```
Public Class Car

  Public Property Passengers As Integer

  Public Shared Sub Fill(c As Car, r As SqlDataReader)
    Passengers = r.GetInt32(0)
  End Sub

End Class

Public Class UsedCar
  Inherits Car

  Public Property PreviousOwner As String

  Public Shared Sub FillUsed(l As Limo, r As SqlDataReader)
    Passengers = r.GetInt32(0)
    PreviousOwner = r.GetString(1)
  End Sub

End Class

Public Sub CreateVehicles()

  Dim c As New Car()
  Car.FillWithStuff(c, GetSqlReader(carId))

  Dim l As New UsedCar()
  UsedCar.FillUsed(l, GetSqlReader(usedCarId)) 'Great
  Car.Fill(l, GetSqlReader(usedCarId)) 'No! << Stop this at once!
  UsedCar.Fill(l, GetSqlReader(usedCarId)) '<<< Even more wrong!

End Sub
```

Comment: And `Limo.FillWithStuff` is even worse...

Comment: I have a feeling you're right. Damn Liskov and his principals! Perhaps my brute force method isn't the greatest, so composition looks like the best alternative at the moment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to require that except to throw an exception.  For instance:

```
Public Shared Sub FillWithStuff(c As Car)
    If Not (TypeOf c Is Car) Then
        Throw New Exception("Must be a Car")
    End If
    Passengers = 4
End Sub
```

However, the simplified example you provide doesn't adequately explain why, in your situation, a limo is not a valid car.  If, in fact, it is not a valid car, then it should not inherit from car.  It is likely that your code ought to be refactored so that car and limo are two unrelated classes that both share the same dependency business class for common functionality.

Comment: Sorry it's not the greatest example tbh. The actual method in question would fill the object from a `SqlDataReader`. The "limo" would equate to a Used Car in fact, whereby it would have an erm, "Original Owner" property. Perhaps I should change my example to that...

Answer (score 1):

Make the constructor private, and have your various Fill() methods instantiate and return a whole new object, or you can move your Fill() code into the constructor itself. Since your methods are pretty closely tied to database results, another option is to mark the constructors as "Friend" and move your Fill() methods to a separate Module that lives with your data layer.

The goal here is that the *only* way to create a car is to use a defined factory method that is in a position to check *at compile time* that the appropriate types match up.